# How to include frontmatter variable in code block in Astro.js?

Tags: astrojs

How do I use a frontmatter tag inside a code block in Astro please? The following code just renders the variable name:

````
```
git clone {frontmatter.url}.git
cd fusionauth-quickstart-javascript-express-web
```
````

And the same for single quotes: `` `frontmatter` ``